# How to format decimal number to x10 notation using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

how to format small decimal number to x10 notation ? For example:

```
0.00298265 --> 2.98265 x 10^-3
9.72157e-9 --> 9.72157 x 10^-9
```

Comment: `10^-3` this isn't valid JS. you probably mean `10e-3`? You can convert a number to an exponential by using [toExponential](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential)

Comment: I didn't know either 10 seconds ago, I just googled it, and now I know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can format the number with `toExponential` and replace the `e`:

```js
console.log(0.00298265.toExponential().replace('e', ' x 10^'));
console.log(9.72157e-9.toExponential().replace('e', ' x 10^'));
```

or with a function:

```js
function format(num) { return num.toExponential().replace('e', ' x 10^'); }
console.log(format(0.00298265));
console.log(format(9.72157e-9));
```

or with your own prototype function:

```js
Number.prototype.toMyFormat = function() { return this.toExponential().replace('e', ' x 10^'); }
console.log(0.00298265.toMyFormat());
console.log(9.72157e-9.toMyFormat());
```